# hibernate how to assign ParameterList for the IN clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, in-clause

I need to use the IN clause in the SQL sentence.
I have data in one table with the type on Int(11).

And Y have a String from another table that is the criteria.

For example, in table A i have the value 3 of type Int.
In table/process B i have the String "0123".

I need to query table A to meet this criteria:
Select * from Table A where attrib_1 IN (0,1,2,3)

Because record n have value 3, it should be returned.

So i'm trying to use .setParameterList, like this:

```
        List<BloqueCruzamiento> bloques = session.createQuery("FROM BloqueCruzamiento AS b WHERE b.anio=:anio AND b.activo=true AND b.grupo=:categoria AND b.pr IN(:pr_set)ORDER BY b.nroParcela, b.cruza, b.pedigree")
                                .setParameter("anio", grupo.getAnio())
                                .setParameter("categoria", grupo.getCategoria())
                                .setParameterList("pr_set", pr_parm)
                                .list();
```

the quid is on "pr_set" parameter.
I want to know how to convert a String , "0123", to a Collection of Integers (0,1,2,3).

So I can pass this parameter to setParameterList() method.

Anapproach that I'm right now is to convert the String to a Char Array, then loop, and convert each element into an Integer Array.

Can somebody give anothe solution ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

you can use code below to get list from String

```
  String s = "0123";
        List<Integer> pr_parm = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
              if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                  pr_parm.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(s.charAt(i))));
              }
          }
          System.out.println(pr_parm);
```

Then you can use the list in your `setParameterList("pr_set", pr_parm)`

Comment: Thanks! I finished using an alternative to yours solution.

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution.

```
String[] sele = grupo.getPr_sel().split(",");
    Integer[] pr_parm_int = new Integer[sele.length];
    for (int x=0; x<sele.length;x++){
        pr_parm_int[x] = Integer.valueOf(sele[x]);
    }
```

the first line is to parse the string and strip comas.